# Not allowing "@" symbol in Codeigniter URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I'm trying to get Codeigniter to accept the "@" symbol in a URL. I've included it as one of the permitted characters below:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_@-';
```

Yet I continue to get his error message:

```
Disallowed Key Characters.
```

Every other character seems to be working fine except for the "@" symbol. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `@` is not a valid character for a URL. It's universal, not CI specific. You'd have to percent encode it

Comment: Even "%40" is returning the error.

Comment: You'll need to allow % as a allowed character to pass %40 I believe

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509028/can-i-use-an-at-symbol-inside-urls/19737890, an @ symbol is valid in a URI. Making it work is another matter though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CodeIgniter routing system translates your url to define controller, action and parameters as keys/values. It checks if the value of a key has permitted characters, and you can configure this with the `$config['permitted_uri_chars']`, but the error message you get is about the key itself not about its value. The `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` doesn't help you to allow the @ symbol in this case. You will find the function `function _clean_input_keys($str)` that checks the keys in system/core/input.php. The % character is not allowed so '%40' will not pass:

```
 if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
```

The only way around this in your case is to avoid this character (maybe translating it) in key parameters.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. This appears to be new in Codeigniter 2.1.0. I was able to use the "@" symbol in the older version.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add proper escaping to your permitted uri string?

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%\.\:_\-';
```

I copied this right from one of my CI sites and %40 is allowed.

Please refer to pekka's comment above about the actual @ symbol.

Comment: It's still not working. This is so odd. It works fine in my older projects, but not this one. I literally just started this, so I can't think of anything that might be causing it.