# Can I use an at symbol (@) inside URLs?

Tags: http, url, character

Is it safe to use an `@` symbol as part of a user? For example, a possible URL would be `http://example.com/@dave`.

The idea is that, nowadays, users are commonly called "@user", so why not make the user page "@username"?

Comment: "users are commonly called @user" - WAT? But yes, you can use @ in a URL.

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong in using @ in url unless it is properly url 
encoded.

Comment: @user1671639: I think you mean "as long as it is properly url encoded".

Comment: Just noticed google maps is now using @ in its URLs: https://www.google.com/maps/@0,0,2z

Answer (score 150):

### Percent-encoded …

You can use the `@` character in HTTP URI paths if you [percent-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) it as `%40`.

Many browsers would display it still as `@`, but e.g. when you copy-and-paste the URI into a text document, it will be `%40`.

### … but also directly

Instead of percent-encoding it, you may use `@` directly in the HTTP URI path.

See the syntax for the [path](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.3) of an URI. Various unrelated clauses aside, the path may consist of characters in the `segment`, `segment-nz`, or `segment-nz-nc` set. `segment` and `segment-nz`  consist of characters from the `pchar` set, which is defined as:

```
pchar = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

As you can see, the `@` is listed explicitly.

The `segment-nz-nc` set also lists the `@` character explicitly:

```
segment-nz-nc = 1*( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / "@" )
```

So, a HTTP URI like this is totally valid:

```
http://example.com/@dave
```

#### Example

Here is an example Wikipedia page:

- [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22@%22_%28album%29)
- copy-and-paste: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22@%22_%28album%29`

As you can see, the `"`, `(`, and `)` characters are percent-encoded, but the `@` and the `_` is used directly.

Comment: Good news! But then, why don't Twitter does this?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger: Could you provide an example URL? I don’t use Twitter, and from what I see they don’t use `@` in URLs anymore, but the old (?) profile URLs still work: [example with percent-encoded `@` (does **not** work!)](https://twitter.com/%40stackexchange) vs. [example using `@` directly (does work!)](https://twitter.com/@stackexchange).

Comment: Interesting! Indeed, works with or without `@` in the case of Twitter. Their inner links do refer the the url without `@` though: https://twitter.com/@stackexchange

Comment: I had to upvote :3
The main issue with @-sign is that its also used by some applications to split username@somesite.com for direct authentication like SSH and such, but  for HTTP plain and good, as soon as its after the first / I don't think there is any problem either.

Comment: should '@' and it's encoded form '%40' be treated as equivalent in a path according to the RFC? In other words does the RFC state that twitter.com/@stackexchange and twitter.com/%40stackexchange SHALL be treated equivalently?

Comment: @RalphCallaway: AFAIK [only *unreserved* characters are equivalent to their percent-encoded form](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20865614/1591669), but the `@` is not [*unreserved*](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-2.3). So consumers must not assume that `%40` and `@` are equivalent.

Comment: For reference, the separate question about this: [Must '@' and '%40' be treated equivalently in URL paths?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36922192/1591669)

Comment: `Many browsers would display it still as @, but e.g. when you copy-and-paste the URI into a text document, it will be %40.`
That's not true for Chrome.

Comment: Sub-delims, including @, are valid in the path -- but caveat they are intended to be used by specific URI schemes and/or URI routing algorithms. They are NOT meant to be actually parts of the path segment -- but separators and operators within a path segment. Ideally `example.com/myResource` and `example.com/myResource@taco/` route to the same execution entry point. or resource, but are interpreted differently by the system/framework/project you are using when it comes to serving http services

Answer (score 49):

Can you use the @-symbol in a URL? - **Yes, you can!**

Note that that @-character, hexadecimal value 40, decimal value 64, is a reserved characters for URI's. It's usage is for things like email-addresses in `mailto:`URI's, for example `mailto:username@somewhere.foo` and for passing username and password information on a URI (which is a bad idea, but possible): `http://username:password@somewhere.foo`

If you want a URL that has an @-symbol in a path you need to encode it, with so called "[URL-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)". For example like this: `http://somewhere.foo/profile/username%40somewhere.foo`

All modern browsers will display this as http://somewhere.foo/profile/username@somewhere.foo, and will convert any typed in @-sign to `%40`, so it's easy to use.

Many web-frameworks will also help you either automatically, or with helper-functions, to convert to and from URL-encoded URL's.

So, in summary: Yes, you can use the **@-symbol** in a URL, but you have to make sure it's encoded, as you can't use the **@-character**.

Comment: +1 perfect.  Instead of relaying on the theory better to give a try.  This is the thing I meant, thanks for making this as nice answer.

Comment: Though encoding is not bad advice, `@` characters do not "need" to be encoded in the path part of a url (http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc3986.html#path)

Comment: Is the reverse true? If I have a URL with an `@`, can I replace the `@` with `%40`? It seems to not be the case for the following:

- URL with `@` works: https://replit.com/@joseville/Prime-Numbers

- but URL with `%40` instead of `@` doesn't work: https://replit.com/%40joseville/Prime-Numbers

Answer (score 13):

In the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) the following characters:

> * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? % # [ ]

are reserved and:

> The purpose of reserved characters is to provide a set of delimiting
> characters that are distinguishable from other data within a URI.

So it is not recommended to use these characters without encoding.

Comment: The @ symbol is explicitly allowed in URL path. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly no.

`@` is a reserved character and should only be used for its intended purpose.

See: http://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/ and http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt

It can be used encoded, but I don't think that is what you were asking.

Apparently modern browsers will handle this. However you asked if this was safe and according to the spec of the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) you should not be using it (unencoded) unless it is for its intended purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question when I tried to search `site:typescriptlang.org @ts-ignore` at Chrome, and then got the result of `This page isn't working, ts-ignore is currently unable to handle this request` and I saw the URL became "http://site:typescriptlang.org%20@ts-ignore/". I felt so refused, then searched `@ symbol's function at an URL` and then I found my answer on Wikipedia.

The full format of the URL is `scheme://userInfo@host:port/path?query#fragment`. so when we search `site:typescriptlang.org @ts-ignore`, the browser will think you want to visit "http://site:typescriptlang.org%20@ts-ignore/". In this URL,  `http` is a scheme, `site:typescriptlang.org%20` is a userInfo ("%20" is escaped by a space character), "ts-ignore/" is a host. Of course, we can't visit the host named "ts-ignore" without a domain.

So, `@` symbol can be a separator between `userInfo` and `host`.