# Why do some query strings work even if parameters are not URL-encoded?

Tags: url, url-encoding

Here's an example:

> https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://journals.plos.org/plosone/s/file?id=wjVg/PLOSOne_formatting_sample_main_body.pdf

The `url` parameter, `http://journals.plos.org/plosone/s/file?id=wjVg/PLOSOne_formatting_sample_main_body.pdf`,  is not encoded.  It contains reserved characters, like the colon, slashes, and question mark.

Why does this still work? And why bother encoding if it works without it?

Answer (score 13):

The [reserved characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) of an URI are mostly used as delimiters -- it doesn’t mean that they may not be used, it only means that they have a special purpose, and if you don’t need them for this purpose, you have to percent-encode them.

The query component starts with the first `?` and ends with the first `#` (if any, otherwise with the end of the URI). For the query component itself, there are no reserved characters defined.

The URI standard RFC 3986 [defines](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) that the query component can contain these characters:

- `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z`
- `0`-`9`
- `/` `?` `:` `@` `!` `$` `&` `'` `(` `)` `*` `+` `,` `;` `=` `-` `.` `_` `~`
- percent-encoded characters

It even explicitly mentions:

> The characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") may represent data within the query component.

---

The query component of your example URI is this:

```
embedded=true&url=http://journals.plos.org/plosone/s/file?id=wjVg/PLOSOne_formatting_sample_main_body.pdf
```

Apart from letters, it contains `=`, `&`, `:`, `/`, `.`, `?`, `_`, all of which are allowed in the query.

Note that the `name=value` format (separated by `&`) in the query component [is just a convention](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/260205/63183), not something defined in the specification.

Comment: So, at the risk of sounding stupid, why are those characters usually encoded in the query string? And could you provide an example in which everything changes or breaks depending on whether the characters are encoded?

Comment: @user123123123: Do you have an example for a URI that percent-encodes its query component although it only contains allowed characters? -- Maybe one reason is [to be on the safe side](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20865614/1591669) (i.e., it’s easy to encode everything, no need to check which characters need it and which don’t)? -- Another reason is of course if the site uses some characters as "custom" delimitiers (like `=` and `&` in the popular convention): if these characters appear as part of the data, they’d have to be percent-encoded (for the site to work, not per the spec).

Answer (score 1):

Because in a url some characters have special meanings, a question mark (?) is used to separate the path from the query, an ampersand (&) is used as a separator between key value pairs. So for characters like this, if we were to use them as a value in a query string the browser would get confused, we use encoding so that we can be sure that the data is not ambiguous. All these characters you have shown are not treated ambiguously as they are used in valid places according to the http URL schema.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the relevant RFC, 1738:

> https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt
>
> 3.3. HTTP
>
> The HTTP URL scheme is used to designate Internet resources
>   accessible using HTTP (HyperText Transfer Protocol).
>
> The HTTP protocol is specified elsewhere. This specification only
>   describes the syntax of HTTP URLs.
>
> An HTTP URL takes the form:
>
> ```
>   http://<host>:<port>/<path>?<searchpart>
> ```
>
> where  and  are as described in Section 3.1. If :
>   is omitted, the port defaults to 80.  No user name or password is
>   allowed.  `<path>` is an HTTP selector, and `<searchpart>` is a query
>   string. The `<path>` is optional, as is the `<searchpart>` and its
>   preceding "?". If neither `<path>` nor`<searchpart>` is present, the "/" 
>   may also be omitted.
>
> Within the `<path>` and `<searchpart>` components, "/", ";", "?" are
>   reserved.  The "/" character may be used within HTTP to designate a
>   hierarchical structure.

The special characters in "http://" only apply to the "protocol" specification at the start of the URL.  It's optional in most browsers (implicitly "http://").

The first "?" separates the "path" from the "searchpart".  Each "&" separates different arguments in the "searchpart".

Your browser *should* differentiate between `?embedded=true` and `&url=http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf`.

'Hope that helps