# What does mean ?page=1

Tags: url, web, page-numbering

Suppose I have an URL like this https://example.com?page=1  or have https://example.com?text=1. Here what does mean by  ?page=1 or ?text=1. Some website like youtube there I can see that they use like https://youtube.com?watch=zcDchec  . What does mean it?

Please explain anyone. I need to know this.

Comment: It is called query string. Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Answer (score 0):

That’s the [**query component**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) (indicated by the first `?`).

It’s [a common convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39294675/1591669) to use `key=value` pairs, separated by `&`, in the query component. But it’s up to the author what to use. And it’s up to the author to decide what it should mean.

In practice, the query component `?page=1` will likely point to page 1 of something, while `?page=2` will point to page 2, etc. But there is nothing special about this. The author could as well have used the path component, e.g. `/page/1` and `/page/2`.