# Change url based on the clicked link (Javascript html)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, blogs

I'm having a problem, or better to say a doubt about how to do.

Let's explain: I have an website similar to a blog where I write articles and they are displayed in the homepage. I want that every time I click on an article it redirects me to the page where the article's content is shown. I save every article in a database with the title, date, content, etc... My doubt is: should I create a .html file for each article or only a file called "article.php" and when I open it, it changes the content getting the data from the database?

Second question: I want that the url of the page changes based of article that I click. For example I click on the article called "Today and Tomorrow", I want that the URL appears as "mysite/today-and-tomorrow/", not "mysite/article.php".
I'm a bit confused about this topic so if anyone can help me i'd be very happy.
Thanks in advice.

I have tried

`var link = 'www.example.com/training/product.html';
        link.split('.html')[0];
        window.history.replaceState( null, null, link );`

But it changes the URL dinamically, so for a few seconds it appears the original URL, in my case it appears "mysite/article.php" and then it changes in "mysite/today-and-tomorrow". I don't think it's properly correct.

I also tried

```
function openArticle(title){
        var rightTitle = $(title).text();
        rightTitle = rightTitle.toLowerCase();
        rightTitle = rightTitle.substring(rightTitle .indexOf(':')+2); 
        rightTitle = rightTitle.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, "-");
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = title.href + "/" + rightTitle;

    }
```

But when I click on the  element the "article.php" remains in the url

Comment: in href of a tage print dynamic url with php

Comment: What have you tried? Questions should have a specific problem and show what you have attempted so far. Currently your question is too broad for stackoverflow's format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should I create a .html file for each article or only a file called "article.php" and when I open it, it changes the content getting the data from the database?

No you dont have to. You can pass article id as a "[query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266970/what-is-the-difference-between-url-parameters-and-query-strings)" to "article.php" and it will take care of providing proper article to the end user.

> I want that the url of the page changes based of article that I click. For example I click on the article called "Today and Tomorrow", I want that the URL appears as "mysite/today-and-tomorrow/", not "mysite/article.php".

You are talking about a feature called "URL Rewriting" which produces nice & meaningful URLs. In order to implement it you need to:

1. Design your database in a way which it can map articles id to its title.(for creating alias)
2. You have to enable **URL Rewrite** in your web server. (for example if you are using Apache as web server, [you need to enable `mod_rewrite`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)).
3. You have to embed your rules for mapping & routing nice URLs to the original ones in a file called `.htaccess`. as a sample [How to write htaccess rewrite rule for seo friendly url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168375/how-to-write-htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-seo-friendly-url)

I was just trying to help you get an overall idea of what you are looking for from technical point of view & as you know Its impossible to cover your required information in just a single post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I enabled mod_rewrite in my httpd.conf file in apache, but what have I to do now?

Comment: Is your article.php handling articles? who has wrote the code?

Comment: article.php contains only the clicked article content. I have all the articles' title displayed in the index.php.  I have wrote all the code

Comment: @Andrea Nice. So, now read [this answer here](stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php#answer-812578). It will help you to map your current 'article.php based URLs' to friendly ones.

Comment: @Andrea [some parts of this article may help you](https://daveismyname.blog/blog/creating-a-blog-from-scratch-with-php-part-2-seo-urls) Now, your only remaining task is creating the `.htaccess` file. Try to keep it as simple as possible for now

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I created a .htaccess file in my folder where is also located the "index.php" file and i tried to wrote "RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

Rewriterule ^index$ index.php" inside it, but it doesn't seem to work. What's wrong?

Comment: @Andrea You're welcome. Its a bit tricky. google about `.htaccess patterns for url rewrite`. Stackoverflow is a community to help developers learn while solving their problems. Try to accomplish this part ( as the major part) yourself. I'm available for hints.

Comment: @Andrea Say, If you find the answer useful you can accept it for future reference.