# What is a query parameter?

Tags: database, apache, solr, parameters, lucene

I’m currently training in Lucidworks Fusion and learning a lot of the vocab. I believe that conceptually, a query is a 'question' you ask the database. And a 'parameter' is a key-value pair.

But what's a good definition of a **query parameter**? Is that a Solr-specific term?

How do query parameters relate to **query strings** and **URL parameters?**

In Solr/Fusion a query parameter might look like: `fq=access:(“user1 OR user2”)`

Fusion's UI defines `fq` as the **parameter** and `access:("user1 OR user2")` as the **parameter value**.

Comment: BTW, I’ve found this link helpful, but the term ‘query parameter’ is not directly used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266970/what-is-the-difference-between-url-parameters-and-query-strings

Comment: Pretty sure they're just referring to parameters (per the question you linked to) passed to a solr query (See solr's [Common Query Parameters](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters)).