# Got Key Error in getting url as text by using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to get data and export to CSV which I have main URL page and second URL main page which I have imported the following of these:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
import csv

def get_page(url):
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    mainpage = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    return mainpage
mainpage = get_page(www.website1.com)
mainpage_parser = BeautifulSoup(mainpage,'html.parser')
secondpage = get_page('www.website2.com')
secondpage_parser = BeautifulSoup(secondpage,'html.parser')
```

The patterns of the data are the same such as Title, Address; thus, the code I
use is "find" or "find_all" in each class; for example,

```
try:
    name = page_parser.find("h1",{"class":"xxx"}).find("a").get_text()
print(name)
except:
print(name)
```

Which it worked.
However, I couldn't get the "lat" and "lon" from url link in this html class:

```
<img class="aaa" alt="map" data-track-id="static-map" width="97" height="142" src="https://www.website.com/aaaaaaa;height=284&amp;lat=18.111&amp;lon=98.111&amp;level=15&amp;returnImage=true">
```

The code I'm trying to get latitude and longitude is:

```
   for gps in secondpage_parser.find_all('img',{"class":"aaa"}, src=True):
      parsed_url = urlparse(gps['src'])
      mykeys = ['lat', 'lon']
      gpslocation = [parse_qs(parsed_url.query)[k][0] for k in mykeys]
   print(gpslocation)
```

But it has Key Error on the "gpslocation = [parse_qs(parsed_url.query)[k][0] for k in mykeys]" line which it indicates "KeyError: 'lat'"

I would like to know which part here I have the mistake or how should I fix it. Please help.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Thank you so much. Since, I'm quite new to Python, do you mean to replace my print(gpslocation) to print(gps['src'], parse_qs(parsed_url.query)) ? I got the same error (Key error of 'lat').

Comment: @StevenRumbalski You are right. The full url doesn't contain any "?". So "query" is invalid for this case right? I'm not sure but if I don't get it wrong, do you mean I should try using string that suits to "&"?

Answer (score 1):

This url has no query string but does have parameters (see [what is the difference between URL parameters and query strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266970/what-is-the-difference-between-url-parameters-and-query-strings)).  So when you try to parse the query string you get an an empty dictionary.  Hence the `KeyError`.

```
"https://www.website.com/aaaaaaa;height=284&amp;lat=18.111&amp;lon=98.111&amp;level=15&amp;returnImage=true"
#                               ^--- semicolon, not question mark
```

Result of `print(parsed_url)`

```
ParseResult(
    scheme='https', 
    netloc='www.website.com', 
    path='/aaaaaaa',
    params='height=284&amp;lat=18.111&amp;lon=98.111&amp;level=15&amp;returnImage=true',
    query='', 
    fragment='')
```

The key here is to parse the parameters.  To fix your code change `parsed_url.query` to `parsed_url.params`:

```
gpslocation = [parse_qs(parsed_url.params)[k][0] for k in mykeys]
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer really makes sense. However, I still have the problem. I've provided the result here with the full Url from the src part. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h55yVubv4N0LHhGaVLVW7gfWp46hrKw9J-Mj02PkBnc/edit?usp=sharing It might help clarify the problem more. Sorry if providing in this .doc format may be disturbing.

Comment: @Meekao:  Yeah, I'm not going to open a .doc.

Comment: I do apologize if it was not appropriate. I find out that the key error existed as I didn't delete _all (I supposed to use .find , not .find_all). So now it follows your direction but the result shows as {}. Could you please suggest a way or any learning sources that I could try figure it out?

Comment: @Meekao: I didn't know the answer when you asked the question.  But I would consider adding a `print(parsed_url)` so you can see how the url has been parsed.  That should give you an angle to start seeking answers.

Comment: I'll try. Thank you so much again.