# RoutePrefix different than Controller name doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

In my WebApiConfig.cs file I have :

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
}
```

I have a OrderController

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Orders")]
public class OrderController : ApiController
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(Order.CreateOrders());
    }
```

As expected, the above code works with url - http://localhost:15660/api/Orders

I got another CustomerController :

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/Customers")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/customers/search
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("search/{location}/{customerName}/{phoneNumber}/{email}")]
    public IHttpActionResult SearchCustomers(string location = null, string customerName = null, string phoneNumber = null, string email = null)
    {
        return Ok(GetCustomersSearchResults(location, customerName, phoneNumber, email));
    }
```

Here, I want to call as /api/Customers/search - but this gives error for no match controller name found. If I rename the prefix to

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Customer")]
```

then it works perfectly well.

In Ordercontroller, `api/Orders`  works perfectly well. In CustomerController, why `api/customers`doesn't work at all and gives error. I googled a lot, found the syntax is correct, but can't figure where am I going wrong that is restricting CustomerController to map with `/api/Customers/search`

Can anyone please help me know how to map CustomerController the way I want to using [RoutePrefix].

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not that the `RoutePrefix` is different from your controller name (you could set `RoutePrefix("abcdefg")` if you wanted), but that you have specified `location`, `customerName`, `phoneNumber` and `email` as required paths in your URL so only a URL such as this would work in your current setup: `/api/Customers/search/EU/cust1/1234/email`.

What you probably want is a query string, not values in your URL. For example: `/api/Customers/search?location=EU&customerName=cust1&phoneNumber=123`. So simply change your route to `[Route("search")]` and such a URL will work!

Tring to pass multiple optional values in through the URL just won't work, what if you pass a URL such as `api/Customers/search/value`. How will the server know if `value` is supposed to be location or customerName?

Here's a question regarding URL parameters and query strings: [What is the difference between URL parameters and query strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266970/what-is-the-difference-between-url-parameters-and-query-strings)

Comment: thanks for your response. URL with NO or Any # or All parameters is working on the above code. With the code, **`/api/Customers/search`** gives error for no matching controller name.  **`/api/Customer/search`** works perfectly. how to make  **`/api/Customers/search`** work.

Comment: @TruptiDalia I am not able to reproduce... when I change to `[RoutePrefix("api/Customer")]` it gives me `No action was found on the controller 'Customer' that matches the request.`. Regardless, my point is that you should not be using the URL to pass parameters anyways.

Comment: hmm, strange. When I use `api/Customers` it produces error and is fine with `api/customer`. Reg URL params, I read the link you shared; couldn't get what I should do to implement in this code. I think you are asking to remove params from the `[Route]`. I had tried adding in function params as `SearchCustomers(string? location = null, string? customerName = null, string? phoneNumber = null, string? email = null)`. Adding **?** to string gives error (as string is non-nullable object). I tried with just `string? location`, but no success. Can you guide what should I do to implement the same.

Comment: No need to change any code other than the route, read the 2nd paragraph in my answer