# TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined when using useParams from react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I can't understand why it gives me the above error. I used the props way with props.match.params.languagename and it works just fine.

I did not include all imports in the code below.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router';

const App = () => {
  const topicsState = useSelector(state => state.topics);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { languagename } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchGitHubTrendingTopics());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const handleRepositoryPages = () => {
    const repositoryPages = topicsState.find(
      topicState => topicState.name === languagename
    );
    if (repositoryPages)
      return <RepositoryPage repositoryPages={repositoryPages} />;
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Header topics={topicsState} />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <Dashboard topics={topicsState} />
          </Route>
          <Route
            path="/language/:languagename"
            exact
            render={handleRepositoryPages()}
          />

          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can only use `useParams` in a component that is a child of your `Router` component, but `App` is the parent in your case.

The `Router` component injects the context containing the `match` into the tree below it which will be read by the `useParams` hook by internally using the `useContext` hook.

Comment: this is incorrect. The op imported from 'react-router'instead of 'react-router-dom' which is causing the issue.

Comment: @ChrisMatthews Actually I looked it up and what you are saying is not correct. `react-router` does export `useParams`. If that wouldn't be the case, OP would also have seen a different error message, that indicates there is no named export `useParams` in that module.

Comment: @ChrisMatthews Proof: https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-fog-eez2n?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ran into exactly the same issue myself and @ChrisMatthews answer is correct. `useParams` from `react-router` is not the same as `useParams` from `react-router-dom`

Comment: I was facing the same issue. I was trying to run my app from local  then this error came up but while running the same app from hosted environment was working fine. As  @ChrisMatthews commented changing import from from 'react-router' to 'react-router-dom'  fixed the issue.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this code , in jest test file for useParams .This worked for me

```
 jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useParams: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ environment: 'dev', service: 'fakeService' }),
}))
```

Hope this works !

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else seeing this error from trying to use `useParams` to get *Query/Search Parameters* and **not** *URL Parameters*, you can use `useLocation` from `react-router-dom`

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
...
...
const query = new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
...
```

> [Difference between Query Parameters and URL Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266970/what-is-the-difference-between-url-parameters-and-query-strings)

> [Query Parameter demo](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters)

[Brwoser Support for `URLSearchParams()`](https://caniuse.com/?search=URLSearchParams)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `MemoryRouter` to fix this issue. For example you have this type of test.

```
describe("Main description", () => {
    it("Component test description", () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<YourComponent />);
    });
});
```

And you get error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined when using useParams

Just wrap your component with `MemoryRouter` and everything will work.

```
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router";

describe("Main description", () => {
    it("Component test description", () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(
           <MemoryRouter>
              <YourComponent />
           </MemoryRouter>
        );
    });
});
```