# Adonis.js api delete route is not working

Tags: adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

**I tried to hit a specific route:**

```
http://127.0.0.1:3333/store/products?productId=4
```

but the server give me this error:

```
"message": "E_ROUTE_NOT_FOUND: Cannot DELETE:/store/products",

"stack": "HttpException: E_ROUTE_NOT_FOUND: Cannot PATCH:/store/products\n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are not hitting the right url and your `route` is wrong.**

The right url with your `route.js` is :

```
http://127.0.0.1:3333/store/products/4
                                     ^- Product id
```

and the `route` :

```js
Route.delete('/products/:productId', 'ProductsController.delete')
//                      ^- use : for url parameter
```

## Routing explanation

[Body data](https://preview.adonisjs.com/guides/http/form-submissions#reading-form-data) & [url parameters](https://preview.adonisjs.com/guides/http/routing#dynamic-urls) are totally different.

Please read : [What is the difference between URL parameters and query strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266970/what-is-the-difference-between-url-parameters-and-query-strings)

### Body data

Request body (json).

Documentation : https://preview.adonisjs.com/guides/http/form-submissions#reading-form-data

**Example url :**

```
http://127.0.0.1:3333/products?name=hello
```

**Route example :**

```js
Route.post('/products', 'MyController.myFunction')
```

**Controller :**

```js
public async myFunction ({ request }: HttpContextContract) {
  const data = request.only(['name'])
  // ...
}
```

### Url parameter

Specify dynamic url parameter.

Documentation : https://preview.adonisjs.com/guides/http/routing#dynamic-urls

**Example url :**

```
http://127.0.0.1:3333/products/1
```

**Route example :**

```js
Route.post('/products/:id', 'MyController.myFunction')
```

**Controller :**

```js
public async myFunction ({ params }: HttpContextContract) {
  const id = params.id
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the points raised by @crbast :
your code seems to hit the HTTP PATCH method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH) instead of the HTTP DELETE you expect