# Datadog custom links (widgets?) on a dashboard

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

Is it possible to add custom links as a widget to DD dashboard?

Among other properties, our Datadog setup displays version of deployed app (which may be different in different environments) and app name.
I was wondering if it was possible to create a dashboard which would contain custom links (widgets?) per each service, where each link will be mapped based on properties:

`https://github.com/${app_name}/compare/${appVersion_1}.substring(..)...${appVersion_2}.substring(..)`

where

- app_name is a name of the app
- appVersion_1 is a version in one environment
- appVersion_2 is a version in another environment

Is there any possibility to achieve that in Datadog?

Answer (score 0):

This might not fit your exact use case, but in terms of displaying custom links in a widget, you can use [Template Variables](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/template_variables/) in a [Notes and Links Widget](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/widgets/note/) to create  links with dynamic values in Markdown.

It does appear to not support Template Variables in the middle of the URL path. They need to be at the end of the path or part of a [query string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39294675/656011).

**Example:**

```
https://example.com/$app_name.value?env=$env.value&some_other_value=something
```

It wouldn't be on a Dashboard, but you might also be able to use the [Service Catalog](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/service_catalog/) and update the relevant services' configuration when your CI/CD deploys updated versions via the [Service Definition API](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/service_catalog/service_definition_api/)