# Can an equals sign appear after the first equals sign in a query parameter?

Tags: http, url, query-string

For example, is this a valid URL:

`http://0.0.0.0:8080/auth/reset?id=AAAAAAAAAAA=&code=uX8kklWhVi-Vhp4BdMRQYBEveEdwQXBFDecLlsT6yBw=`

From what I've researched it seems to be discouraged (but I haven't found anything definitive), but all the decoders I've tested it with decode it correctly. This includes:

- Google Chrome
- Firefox
- NodeJS' `decodeURIComponent`

Answer (score 17):

The `key=value` format in the query component [is just a convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39294675/1591669).

The `=` is [allowed in the query component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38816380/1591669), and it has no reserved meaning there.

So yes, it is a valid URI.

How the parameters get parsed depends on the specific implementation. As the parameters are typically separated by a `&`, it would make sense to interpret additional `=` characters as part of the value.