# Are equals signs allowed *within* a data value in URI query string

Tags: url, uri, query-string, specifications

In a standard URI query string, am I allowed to use an equals (`=`) sign unencoded within the value part of a query component. In other words, am I allowed another equals sign after the first equals sign but before the `&` which separates the components? E.g. is the following valid?

`index.html?param1=a_value_with_=_sign&param2=12=13`

From my reading of [What's valid and what's not in a URI query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366260/whats-valid-and-whats-not-in-a-uri-query), which summarises RFC 3986, the use of equals within the component does *not* "conflict with a reserved character's purpose as a delimiter", as it is clear in this case that only the first equals in each component serves as a delimiter. So I think I should be able to do this.

Comment: [Can an equals sign appear after the first equals sign in a query parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42506034/1591669)

Comment: Thanks. I guess that essentially confirms my interpretation. Sorry I didn't spot this as a dup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can an equals sign appear after the first equals sign in a query parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506034/can-an-equals-sign-appear-after-the-first-equals-sign-in-a-query-parameter)