# Understanding URL symbols and usage

Tags: php, url

Would like some help to understand this URL a little better.

> something/?page=2&agent=2725

I'm aware that with `$_GET["page"]` I can get the **'page'** number and presumably **'agent'** code also via the same approach.

I'm trying to understand the role of the **'&'** symbol there. By the outlook I can guess it combines ***page*** number and the ***agent*** code. Is my understanding there right?

What instance you can use this **&** symbol and how is it helpful?

Comment: Its simply the syntax. & is the separator between two GET parameters in the URL. Means, as you said, `$_GET["page"]` would be 2 and `$_GET["agent"]` would be 2725. They have nothing to do together and the "&" symbol shoudln't be interpreted as a "AND... its more like a separator. Like you would write `page: 2, agent: 2725` ... in this case the `,` is the `&`. Hope you understand. Don't let you confuse from this symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s look at this HTTP URI:

```
http://example.com/something/?page=2&agent=2725#foo
```

This is the URI’s [query component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) (indicated by the first `?`, terminated by the first `#` or the end of the URI):

```
page=2&agent=2725
```

As far as the general URI syntax is concerned, the `&` is not different from the `p`, the `a`, or the `=` ([see all allowed characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38816380/1591669)): they all represent data in the query component.

[A common convention is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39294675/1591669) to use the query component for name–value pairs. In this convention, the `&` is used as delimiter, separating the pairs:

```
name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3
```

Answer (score 0):

the "?" means: Get-Parameters are following, the "=" seperates key and value and the "&" seperates different keys with their corresponding value. So, the "&" just means "there is another Get-Parameter following".

test.php?key1=value2&key2=value2&key3=value3&...

Answer (score 0):

`&` this symbol is used to separate each parameters on the URL. So basically when the request params is parsed by the server, it knows that every `&` is another variable.

> Also this format is known as urlencoded.

You can check and read more here. 
[URLENCODED](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)