# Characters a URL can't end with?

Tags: url, sanitization

What characters (if any) can a web browser URL (http/https) **not** end with?

As far as I can tell, control characters aren't used e.g.

- `\0` nil.
- `\t` tab.
- `\n` newline.
- space (from testing seems this is stripped).

Is there a complete list of such characters?

Answer (score 2):

There are three cases how a URI can end:

- with the path component (if it has no query/fragment)

  ```
    http://example.com/
    http://example.com/path
    http://example.com/path/path
  ```
- with the query component (if it has no fragment)

  ```
    http://example.com/?query
    http://example.com/path?query
    http://example.com/path/path?query
  ```
- with the fragment component

  ```
    http://example.com/#fragment
    http://example.com/path#fragment
    http://example.com/path/path#fragment
    http://example.com/?query#fragment
    http://example.com/path?query#fragment
    http://example.com/path/path?query#fragment
  ```

The [URI standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) doesn’t place any restrictions on the end of these three components ([Path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3), [Query](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4), [Fragment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5)), so the same characters are allowed that can appear anywhere else in the components:

- [characters allowed in the **path** component](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/91211/17633)
- [characters allowed in the **query** component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38816380/1591669)
- [characters allowed in the **fragment** component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26119120/1591669)

> space (from testing seems this is stripped)

URIs can have (multiple) space characters at the end (in all three cases), but they have to be percent-encoded. Spaces aren’t allowed unencoded, no matter where.

```
http://example.com/path-ending-with-four-spaces-%20%20%20%20
```

If a user agent tries to convert user input into a valid URI (i.e., percent-encoding all characters that can’t appear in the component), it might assume that trailing spaces aren’t intended to be part of the URI, and strip them.

The same goes for tab and newline characters. They can be part of URIs if percent-encoded.