# URL Query string encoding of JavaScript's child objects

Tags: javascript, url, encoding, javascript-objects

I am sending following data to API, but not receiving values of child objects. How to properly URL encode child objects in javascript?

**Data:**

```
    var details = {
      OrderDate: "10-Sep-2020",
      OrderID: "1011539",
      Dated: "27-feb-2021",
      CreatedBy: 0012,
      tblAuthorityLetterDtls: [
        {
          ProductCode: "0010005",
          Qty: "1"
        },
        {
          ProductCode: "0010005",
          Qty: "5"
        },
        {
          ProductCode: "0010005",
          Qty: "3"
        }
      ]
    }
```

**Loop code I am using to URL encode data:**

```
    var formBody = [];
    for (var property in details) {
      if (property != "tblAuthorityLetterDtls"){
        var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
        var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
        formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
      }else{
        var innerval = details[property];
          for (var i = 0; i < details[property].length; i++) {
          var formBodyinner = [];
          for (var innerproperty in innerval[i]) {
            if (innerval[i].hasOwnProperty(innerproperty)) {
              var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(innerproperty);
              var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(innerval[i][innerproperty]);
              formBodyinner.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
            }
            formBodyinner.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
          }
          formBody.push("tblAuthorityLetterDtls" + "=" + formBodyinner);
        }
      }
    }
    formBody = formBody.join("&");
```

Comment: Did my answer help you resolve your problem? if so, please mark it as accepted by ticking the V icon to its left. if not, let me know and I'll try to further help.

Answer (score 0):

Running your encoding code over your object, we get:

```
OrderDate=10-Sep-2020&OrderID=1011539&Dated=27-feb-2021&CreatedBy=10&tblAuthorityLetterDtls=ProductCode=0010005,ProductCode=0010005,Qty=1,Qty=1&tblAuthorityLetterDtls=ProductCode=0010005,ProductCode=0010005,Qty=5,Qty=5&tblAuthorityLetterDtls=ProductCode=0010005,ProductCode=0010005,Qty=3,Qty=3
```

Note that:

1. This string is a [valid query string per RFC 3986](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31300627/3002584), so that *per the spec* it doesn't *have* to be encoded. However, your API provider [*may*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809739/why-do-some-query-strings-work-even-if-parameters-are-not-url-encoded#comment65004075_38816380) have applied some assumptions upon some delimters, assigning them a special meaning and hence making them "reserved".
   For example, maybe your API provider doesn't allow using `=` multiple times within a single query string parameter. This is just an example, of course.
2. This string contains duplicate child values (each `ProductCode` and `Qty` appears twice).

I suggest you just pass the entire string to `encodeURIComponent` and see if it works. If it does, you can then gradually apply `encodeURIComponent` for each part of the query string and see what's the problematic part.

Otherwise, you'd have to advise your API provider.