# AT symbol "@" in file name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load a file using jQuery that contains the "@" symbol in the file name. Other files will load, however files with "@" do not. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks.

```
var file = $(this).text();  //div with file name
$.get(file, function(data) {
```

Comment: In this case your file name is a URL. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509028/at-symbol-inside-urls

Comment: What does your server do with it, what's the response (check network tab in devtools)? What exactly is the URL?

Comment: It's a div containing a file name that is on the server. jQuery reads the file and returns the contents. It works for file names without "@".

Comment: @Sergiu replacing "@" with "%40" did not work.

Comment: Well of course it does not work. Your webserver must be configured to convert `%40` back to an `@` char.

Comment: Can you provide any guidance on how to configure this (Apache Linux)?