# @ sign as url parameter separator?

Tags: url, standards, url-parameters

While browsing the new Google Maps I saw that they are using an `@` sign instead of `?` to seperate the url-path from the query parameters, like:

https://www.google.com/maps/@38.1158476,-96.2044115,6z

The coordinates after the `@` change as you are navigating around the map, but without a browser refresh. Bookmarking works fine with this.

[Wikipedia does not mention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) anything about this, [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) only shows the `@` sign as a possibility for username/password authentication.

Is this a standardised feature or a proprietary browser functionality? Is this feature safe to use, and how do I use it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@38.1158476,-96.2044115,6z` is *not* the [query component](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.4). It’s still part of the [path component](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.3).

The [`@` character can be used in the path, even without percent-encoding it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737890/1591669).

So from the URI standard perspective, there is nothing special about this URI. There could have been used any other (or no) character instead.

I assume Google uses the `@` here because users might read it as "at", which is suitable for "*at <location>*".