# what is @ letter in google maps URL

Tags: url, properties, maps

what is @ letter in google maps URL 
is it a property in the url like Get method ?

%see the attached img
https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/t1.0-9/10636306_10204474095673662_3891237167715233361_n.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It’s just a character with no reserved meaning (it’s [valid to use in the path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737890/1591669), even without percent-encoding).

Instead of

```
https://www.google.com/maps/@38.1158476,-96.2044115,6z
```

they could have also used one of these:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/at-38.1158476,-96.2044115,6z
https://www.google.com/maps/38.1158476,-96.2044115,6z
https://www.google.com/maps/loc/38.1158476,-96.2044115,6z
…
```

They [probably](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22249968/1591669) chose the `@` because it can be read as "at", which makes sense because coordinates follow ("*at <location>*").

Comment: not it is ajax but i do not know how the add this or modify

Comment: @user3672223: I don’t understand what you mean.