# Is @ character common in HTTP address path? And can we use it in HTTP address path?

Tags: http, url

I'm working on a website route path settings. We have a path, say, `/folders/` to list all folders, and there're `/folders/:name` paths for folders.

When it comes to the path for folder creation, my college wants to use `/folders/:name/add` for route matching with the `Add Folder` button navigates to `/folders/self/add`. I have to agree that this `/folders/:name/add` route matching is better than the explicit `/folder/self/add` route matching in some way that in the future, if somebody wants to add a `/folders/:name/add` route matching for another purpose, he/she would see there are duplicates and hence the conflict is avoided.

With an unused parameter for route-matching makes me nervous. Besides,  the user can manually enter any arbitrary `/folder/whatsoever/add` that will also navigate to the folder creation page.

Therefore I suggested `/folders/@/add`, in which `@` is an illegal character for a folder name. At the same time, this `@` can stand for `actions`.

But my college said he cannot agree with the `/folders/@/add` route matching for that the character `@` is rare in HTTP address path.

It's really hard to google the answer for this *is it common or not for an HTTP address path having the `@` character in it* question.

In your experiences, what's the answer?

Thanks.

Comment: [Can I use an at symbol (@) inside URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19509028/1591669) --- Google Maps seem to use it, for example: [@ sign as url parameter separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22221252/1591669)

Comment: @unor Thx for the link. I finally convinced my colleague to accept my suggestion. And I think for Google Maps, @ means `at` as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22249968/2279231).