# Is the "@" character valid in a URL after the hostname?

Tags: url, uri

"@" is certainly allowed in this case:

- [http://user:pass@domain.com/foo](http://user%3apass@domain.com/foo)

However, in theses cases:

- http://www.foo.com/@bar
- http://www.foo.com/?email=a@b.com

Are they 'ok' or should the "@" be encoded?
Similarly, if they are 'ok', does it make the host portion "bar" and "b.com" respectively?

I took a look at the rfc (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) and page 45 uses this example:

```
ftp://cnn.example.com&story=breaking_news@10.0.0.1/top_story.htm
```

to indicate that the "@" means "10.0.0.1" is the host, but I'm not sure because the query portion didn't start correctly (no "?"). (Also it then mentions "attacks" and I got confused.)

The background: I am trying to determine if Steven Levithan's regex is correct in parsing "http://www.foo.com/@bar" as having a host of "bar":
http://stevenlevithan.com/demo/parseuri/js/

Comment: i would encode it just to be safe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [At (@) symbol inside URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509028/at-symbol-inside-urls)

Comment: I think you are right and it is a duplicate. (Such a difficult one to google for!) However, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509028/at-symbol-inside-urls has conflicting answers, so maybe this has some use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you are mentioning is used in the RFC to illustrate how a URI like that can be deceiving to humans. In this case `cnn.example.com&story=breaking_news` would be the user info portion of the URI, in the same way as `user:pass` is in your first example.

As far as whether or not `@` is allowed in the URI itself, as far as I can tell it is.

If you look at pages 48 and 49 you'll find (among other things) the following rules:

```
URI           = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
hier-part     = "//" authority path-abempty / *snip*
authority     = [ userinfo "@" ] host [ ":" port ]
path-abempty  = *( "/" segment )
segment       = *pchar
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

Applying  this to `http://www.foo.com/@bar` we find that `scheme` is `http`. `authority` does only contain the mandatory `host` portion which is `www.foo.com` (`userinfo` and `port` are both optional). Together with this `authority` component `hier-part` has a `path-abempty` component which consits of a single repetition `/@bar`. The `segment` consists of 4 repetitions of `pchar`: `@`, `b`, `a` and `r`. As such `bar` is not the hostname.

How well any given browser and or webserver follows the RFC on the other hand is an entierly different question.

**Disclaimer:** I am no expert, and it's been a while since I looked at [ABNF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234) in general.