# Must '@' and '%40' be treated equivalently in URL paths?

Tags: http, url, uri, rfc1738

Follow up to [Can I use an at symbol (@) inside URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509028/can-i-use-an-at-symbol-inside-urls)

Based on the [top voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737890/84130), the `@` is not a reserved character in the URL path (although it is in the host).

However, given an `@` in the path, is the URL-encoded form interchangeable? In other words, is `twitter.com/@user` strictly equivalent to `twitter.com/%40user`?

In practice it seems like they're often used interchangeably, but curious if that is strictly the case (e.g. `AbC@gmail.com` is technically different from `abc@gmail.com`, but nearly everyone treats them the same).

More broadly, when do characters and there URL-encoded version need to be treated the same, and when different (e.g. `example.com/path%2Fasdf` is NOT the same as `example.com/path/asdf`) …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URIs `http://twitter.com/@user` and `http://twitter.com/%40user` are **not** equivalent.

---

The URI standard is [STD 66](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66), which currently maps to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (which updates [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738)).

The section [6.2.2.2.  Percent-Encoding Normalization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.2.2) defines how to normalize percent-encoded URIs to compare them for equivalence (after uppercasing hexadecimal digits `A`-`F`, as defined by [6.2.2.1 Case Normalization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6.2.2.1)).

It says:

> […] some URI producers percent-encode octets that do not require percent-encoding, resulting in URIs that are equivalent to their non-encoded counterparts.  These URIs should be normalized by decoding any percent-encoded octet that corresponds to an unreserved character, as described in [Section 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3).

The linked section 2.3 lists the *unreserved characters*, which are:

- ALPHA (`a`-`z`, `A`-`Z`)
- DIGIT (`0`-`9`)
- `-` `.` `_` `~`

This sections also states that, even in case no normalization happens:

> URIs that differ in the replacement of an unreserved character with its corresponding percent-encoded US-ASCII octet are equivalent: they identify the same resource.

The `@` is not part of the "unreserved" set. It’s part of the ["reserved" set](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2), where it says:

> URIs that differ in the replacement of a reserved character with its corresponding percent-encoded octet are not equivalent.