# Search users by part of email that contains @ . Auth0

Tags: lucene, auth0

I try to find users by part of email that contains `@` symbol. 
If I use pattern like `email:*domain.co*` all is fine and I have the next requst to auth0:

```
https://subDomainName.auth0.com/api/v2/users?q=email%3A%20*domain.co*
```

but when I use `email:*@domain.co*` it doesn't return users

request:

```
https://subDomainName.auth0.com/api/v2/users?q=email%3A%20*%40domain.co*
```

`%40` is  `@` symbol

How can I use `@` symbol in a query?

Comment: You want to use like query with @ on sql?

Comment: I want to find users by part of email. in t-sql I use _select * from users where email like '%@domain.com'_. I want to do the same using this api. When **q=email:*domain.com** it works, but when **q=email:*@domain.com** it doesn't work

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509028/can-i-use-an-at-symbol-inside-urls

Comment: I use the auth0 api. I try to get list of users using search pattern and it doesn't work when I use @ in a query. the method is described here https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/get_users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found the way.
You should use the next next parameter in the query:

```
q=email.raw:*domain*
```