# nodejs express wildcard route not working

Tags: node.js, express, wildcard

I'm doing an API in nodejs with express as router.

Now i'm trying to implement an client-id and an apikey to add some security to the API, and the problem that i'm facing is the next:

One of my API call is like this:
`router.get("roles/get-objects/:mail/:filter*?")`
So this means, that i can request an object like this:
`/roles/get-objects/mail@mail.com/customer`

Now the tricky part begins... when I needed to stablish a middleware to read an client-id and an apikey to verify that the client is authorized to se the API, so I did this:

In the declaration of the middleware, I use this wildcard:
`router.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
XXXX})`

The thing is, I have tried in the middleware, as a wildcard everything...
I want that any API call is filtered thru that middleware, but apparently I can't find the right wildcard for it...

When I use /roles/* as wildcard, if I do a request to `/roles` it does work, but when I use the complete URL like: `/roles/get-objects/mail@mail.com/customer` it doesn't go thru my middleware.

So anybody has any idea? i'm starting to loose my mind

Thank you so much to all of you!

**EDIT:**
Now i'm using this middleware declaration:
`router.use(function (req, res, next) {XXXX})`

So when I call:
`/roles/get-objects/`

It's executed, the problem is when I add the email to the route:
`/roles/get-objects/mail@mail.com`

The app goes directly to the route that i have for that, but omits my middleware:
router.get("roles/get-objects/:mail",

I don't understand why is this happening, apparently everything should go thru my middleware first, or am I wrong?

Comment: could it be that the @-sign is not allowed?

Comment: @lumio `@` is allowed, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509028/can-i-use-an-at-symbol-inside-urls

Comment: Cool! Learned something new. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to establish a middleware to check all HTTP request whose URL starting with `/roles/`, the middleware should be placed **before** any other specific router definition:

```
router.use('/roles', function(req, res, next) {...});
...
router.get('/roles/get-objects/:mail', ...);
```

If the middleware is defined after specific route, when HTTP request comes in, the specific route is targeted and processed, the middleware won't be executed any more:

```
router.get('/roles/get-objects/:mail', ...);
...
router.use('/roles', function(req, res, next) {...}); // This middleware logic won't execute when request is sent to '/roles/get-objects/some-email', as the request has already been handled and response is already sent to browser.
```

Comment: that was the issue, i was declaring first the get, and then the middleware! Thank you so much :)