# At-sign symbol in password make problem when add username and password to git clone url

Tags: git, command-line

I want to clone git repository by adding username and password for authenticate like this:

```
https://myUserName:myPassWord@myGitRepositoryAddress/myAuthentificationName/myRepository.git
```

But my password includes `@` (like `123@asd`) and this cause problem in git repository url and I get error like this:

```
https://123@myGitRepositoryAddress/myAuthentificationName/myRepository.git
```

and first `@` consider as seperator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use an at symbol (@) inside URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509028/can-i-use-an-at-symbol-inside-urls)

Answer (score 3):

In order to use the `@` symbol in your URL, you have to use [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). The percent code for `@` is `%40`. Therefore, if you want to clone your repo with the username `user` and the password `123@asd`, you have to use the following url:

```
https://user:123%40asd@myGitRepositoryAddress/myAuthentificationName/myRepository.git
```