# Image name "+" why throw 404

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a web page using laravel where the images of the products i am getting from the backend via url: https://examole.com/cache/medium/product/3954/Wl2 +spitak.jpg.
If the name of the image contains "+", then I cant get an image in front and receive a 404 erro, but in the admin, I can see the image. If I change the "+" symbol for example to "-" then I can get the image on my front. Any solutions???

Comment: Use this on your blade `{{ rawurlencode(str_replace('+','%2B', $file_name)) }}`

Comment: @sta that's double encoding with unnecessary and bad practice `str_replace`.

Answer (score 2):

[`+` is a reserved symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19509104/1948292).

You can use it but with all URLs in HTML, the special characters need to be [encoded](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

What you probably have:

```
<img src="https://examole.com/cache/medium/product/3954/Wl2 +spitak.jpg">
```

What it should be:

```
<img src="https://examole.com/cache/medium/product/3954/Wl2%20%2Bspitak.jpg">
```

Encoding the blankspace to `%20` and the `+` symbol to `%2B`.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes PHP can be a bit finicky with things like this. Try replacing `+` with its UTF-8 escape character, `%2B`