# Create Custom Route in Blazor Wasm

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am using blazor wasm, I want to create a custom routing that starts with the letter @ and ends with the User's username. I wrote the following code, but it seems that the routing cannot be set this way

the route I expect  `https://localhost:5000/@michel`

```
@page "/@{Username}"

@code {

[Parameter]
public string Username { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't segment routes with ascii characters.  "@" is just an ascii character.  So:

```
https://localhost:5000/@michel
```

looks for a route "@michel", and will only find one if you have this on a page:

```
@page "/@michel"
```

Put in a separator like this:

```
@page "/@/{UserName}"
```

and that will work.

If you want to route using "@" as a special character (like "/") then I believe you're into building a custom router.

Comment: There is no problem using the @ character in url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509028/can-i-use-an-at-symbol-inside-urls 
I want to know how I can route a default character first, not a segment like `/@/michel`

Comment: I didn't say there was a problem with @.  I'm just pretty sure you can't use it as a route separator in the standard router - happy to be wrong and someone show us how.   So I think the answer to "I want to know how I can route a default character first" is write yourself a router.

Comment: If I save the username in the database as ‍`@michel`, how can I be sure that if the user starts the address with @, the component I want will receive the request, because it is possible that other routes match this address.

Comment: ??? [short for polite question]  Are you saying "https://localhost:5000/@michel" and "https://localhost:5000/michel" should both route to the same place and `UserName` should capture "michel"?

Comment: No, I want to save the username with @ in the database and if the user enters this address ‍`localhost:5000/@michel`
The request must reach the component I want because it is possible that other routes will match and the wrong component will be loaded.

Comment: If you want to save the username with @ in database, I think you don't need to let user enters UserName starting with `@` in URL, you can `UserName = "@"+UserName;` in `OnInitialized()` method.

Comment: @jack - see my answer to your other (very similar) question.