# read/get @ value from url in PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, url-parameters

I'm currently developing a site in which a user can create a user area with a user directory created at registration such as `myWebsite.com/user/myUserName`

Now I've seen YouTube & TikTok (and presumably more) use an url like `myWebsite.com/user/@myUserName` (note the "@")

So my question is how do I read these? if a user visits `myWebsite.com/user/@myUserName` how do I read the @ data?

I've searched many SO questions and Google before asking this and can't seen to find answers. only for standard url params or hashtags but not @, help!

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737890/9455573) ?

Comment: How do you currently read the username from `myWebsite.com/user/myUserName`?

Comment: @brombeer I don't need to read the current url data back since the url is already the correct directory, however if i wanted to use myWebsite.com/user/@myUserName the at part would have to be read and coverted (fprwarded ?) to myWebsite.com/user/myUserName would it not

Comment: So if a user visits `myWebsite.com/user/myUserName` you probably show information about the user with the username `myUserName`. How do you currently know that `myUserName` is the username the user wants to get information on? You mentioned "_the correct directory_", is `myUserName` a directory?

Comment: @brombeer yes indeed, users get their own directory so myUserName dir would be created if you register with username myUserName (checks are done)

Comment: Wouldn't that result in an URL like `myWebsite.com/user/myUserName/`  - slash at the end, since it's a folder? (Btw, that sounds like an oooooldschool way to do it, you might want to take a look at "rewriting"/ModRewrite, depending on what server you use - which would also solve your `@` problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

You can use the `window.location.pathname` API to read the path name, parse it into an array and then filter out the only item that starts with an "@" character.

```js
// take the entire path from the window and split them into an array with /
const paths = window.location.pathname.split('/')
// paths = ["","user","@myUserName"]

// pick out the first item in the array starting with an "@:
const userName = paths.find((item) => item.at(0) === "@")
// userName = "@myUserName"
```

### Explanation

Firstly, you need to understand the structure of a URL https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL

Looking at your example, the user id should be part of the path. To get the entire path of `/my-path/@user-id`, you can use window.location.pathname [(MDN reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/pathname).

From there on, you can parse the path to get the user id with JavaScript

### Alternative Answer

Or you can just use Regex and capture anything that comes after "@"

```js
const final = window.location.pathname.match("@.*").at(0)
// note: not a complete solution because it captures the other parts of the URL following the `/@username/` path
```