# how to sent parameter in redirect - php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

the following code gives me an error. I want to call a function and pass a parameter to it with php codeigniter.

```
redirect(base_url() . 'MainController/Student_Login($user_email)')
```

here MainController is the Controller name, Student_Login is the function $user_email is a variable that holds the user email id. I have also tried sending it through url. e.g.

```
redirect(base_url() . 'MainController/Student_Login/.$user_email.')
```

Please Help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending data along with a redirect in CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837467/sending-data-along-with-a-redirect-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 6):

There is no need of adding `base_url` with redirect.

Just try

`redirect('mainController/Student_Login/'.$user_email)`

when **user_email** you will receive as argument in **student_Login** funciton

Comment: What should I do if I have to call a function of another Controller and pass the $user_email variable to it?

Comment: same way `redirect('CONTROLLER_NAME/FUNCTION_NAME/'.$email)`

Comment: It gives me error: The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: It's because codeigniter won't allow a character like `@` and some other characters in URL so it will throw error like that. If you want to allow than go to your `application/config/config.php` and change `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';` to `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = " "`  If still it won't work you can check the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334700/not-allowing-symbol-in-codeigniter-url)

Comment: Is there anyway to pass it by parameter like: redirect(base_url() . 'Student_Controller/Student_Login('.$user_email.')');

Answer (score 4):

You can pass it over session. If you want it available next request only, put it in session flash data.

First controller

```
public function method1()
{
    // if not loaded session library in APPPATH . 'config/autoload.php' load it in here

    $this->session->set_flashdata('user_email', $user_email);

    redirect('secondcontroller/method2', 'refresh');
}
```

Second controller

```
public function method2()
{
    // if not loaded session library in APPPATH . 'config/autoload.php' load it in here

    $user_data = $this->session->flashdata('user_email');

    // when flash data is set, after this request it will be unset from $_SESSION array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it as with out `base_url()`

```
redirect('MainController/Student_Login/'.$user_email);
```

And in method you get it using

```
function Student_Login($user_email){
    echo $user_email;
    //...
}
```

Comment: What should I do if I have to call a function of another Controller and pass the $user_email variable to it?

Comment: just `redirect('/controller/method/parameter');`

Comment: it gives me this error: The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: Which characters create problem share your url!!

Comment: This is what I did.                 redirect('/Student_Controller/Student_Login/'.$user_email); here $user_email is an email address of a user

Comment: What is the value of `$user_email` ??

Comment: the value of $user_email is fareedshujon12@gmail.com

Comment: this is my function where I get it:         
        public function Student_Login()
        {   
            $email = $this->uri->segment(3);
            echo $email;
        }

Comment: Add @ in `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_@-';`

Comment: Is there anyway to pass it by parameter like: redirect(base_url() . 'Student_Controller/Student_Login('.$user_email.')');

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
redirect(base_url() . "MainController/Student_Login/" . $user_email);
```

or

```
$url = base_url() . "MainController/Student_Login/" . $user_email;
redirect($url);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try  this

```
 redirect(base_url()."MainController/Student_Login/".$user_email);
```