# How to Redirect with 2 parameter to a method of different controller which is in a folder CI?

Tags: codeigniter

Please see the file directory

```
 controller
    -student
    --dashboard_student.php
    --edit_profile.php
```

//at edit_profile.php

```
public function method1(){
$parameter_1='XYZ';
$parameter_2='ABC';
redirect('student/dashboard_student/method2/'.$parameter_1.'/'.$parameter_2); 
}
```

//at dashboard_student.php

```
 public function method2($parameter_1,$parameter_2){
    echo $parameter_1.','.$parameter_2;
    }
```

when I run this code, found:

```
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.
```

But Expect:

```
XYZ,ABC
```

Comment: Is this a question or else an answer about how to redirect?

Comment: Sorry it is a question...

Comment: can you explain what was the issue for you in this question

Comment: take reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38121544/how-to-sent-parameter-in-redirect-php-codeigniter

Comment: It is a good idea to explain what happens when the code runs and how it was different than you expected.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

please use for getting value's from parameter in CI

```
$this->uri->segment(x);
```

where x belong to your parameter number.

Comment: Is this the answer related to your question?

Question is about how to redirect

Comment: Not exactly!! but i found it as a different way... I also  found a concept of MY_Controller by which it become eazy